# kotlin naming conventions for "duplicate" property names?

Tags: kotlin, coding-style

They're not really duplicate, of course, I just don't know how to describe the concept in a short manner. It's about property getters that are only there to expose a transform of another property whose access is hidden. Here, let me explain in a piece of code:

```
class MyClass {
    internal val _children = mutableListOf<MyClass>()
    val children: List<MyClass> get() { return _children.toList() }
}
```

Children is modifiable internally, and should also be exposed to the outside world, but they shouldn't be able to modify the list. A fairly understandable situation, I think.

I have intuitively chosen the _name convention I have encountered in Angular (typescript) and c#, where this seems commonly used in similar situations.
But intellij is complaining that by convention, *all* property names should start with a lower-case letter.

Is there another naming convention for this kind of thing in Kotlin, or is the IDE simply not seeing what I'm trying to do (which would be unsurprising) and I should just ignore it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the coding conventions suggest
prepending the private backing property names with an underscore, just as you did with `_children`:

> **Names for backing properties**
>
> If a class has two properties which are conceptually the same but one is part of a public API and another is an implementation detail, use an underscore as the prefix for the name of the private property:
>
> ```
> class C {
>     private val _elementList = mutableListOf<Element>()
>
>     val elementList: List<Element>
>          get() = _elementList
> }
> ```

See [Property names](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#property-names)